# Combine desired rows together in Excel

Tags: excel, row

I have a 1000 X 5 data in Excel. I'm interested in data in R3, R10, R17......( every 7 rows between) and I want to combine all the desired rows together and put the data in one single cell. 
Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Put the data in a single cell ? What kind of data is there ? What do you want to do with it ?

Comment: data are just numbers. I want to put them all together in Mathematica after this step.@AlexandreP.Levasseur

Comment: You have to be more precise. Please update your post to tell us how you want to join your data. From your comment to the answer below we see you don't want a sum which would be a logical choice to "put the data in one single cell" when talking about numbers. Please provide an example if you can so that you can receive the best possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple Excel formula to do what you're asking:

```
{=SUM(R3:R1003*MOD(ROW(R3:R1003),7)=3))}
```

I took the instructions from here:

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/sum-every-nth-row.html

Comment: Thank you. But I want combine data together, divide them by comma, I do not mean adding the values up together.

Comment: what is "divide them by comma"?